# What is Resetting Defaults and Why Should You Do It? CSS

Tags: css

In my Codecademy course, there was a lesson about Resetting Defaults through:

```html
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I didn't really understand what this does. From my understanding, resetting defaults sets all the elements that have not been assigned a certain property the property specified in the `*` selector above.

Is this the correct definition and what is its use?

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding, resetting defaults sets all the elements that
> have not been assigned a certain property the property specified in
> the * selector above.

Yes, that's about correct. It's mainly used to change the values from their default values to a certain value specified by us

Resetting your styles, commonly referred to as **CSS Reset** or **Reset CSS** is the process of resetting (or more accurately – setting) the styles of all elements to a baseline value so that you avoid **cross-browser** differences due to their built-in default style settings.

In case you didn’t know, every browser has its own default ‘user agent’ stylesheet, that it uses to make unstyled websites appear more legible.

**Need for CSS Reset -**

Using a CSS Reset, we can force every browser to have all its styles reset to a value specified by us, thus avoiding cross-browser differences as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

asterisk `*` selects all of the elements in the document and whatever style you insert will override the style for all elements unless that element's style is explicitly specified.

For example:

```
    * {
         margin: 0;
     }

     div {
         margin: 4px;
     }
```

This styling will change the margin of all the elements in the document to 0 which will then be overridden by the `div` element. So, div will have a margin of 4px.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different default stylings for different elements. And, it's also used because sometimes you just want to define everything yourself.